# Regex em javascript para match parcial em URL

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu preciso escrever um regex em javascript que contenha um pedaço específico de URL, porém não estou conseguindo fazer, principalmente por se tratar de uma url com "/".

Exemplo: Qualquer "like" ou parcial match para "www.url.com/foo"

```
www.url.com/foo/bar/send/123   - true
www.url.com/foo/doe/get/123    - true
www.url.co/foo/doe/get/123     - false
http://www.url.com/foo/get/123 - true
http://www.url.co/foo/doe/123  - false
```

Alguma idéia de como fazer um regex "genérico" para qualquer outras urls também?

Comment: O `url.com` é fixo o que vier depois pode ser qualquer coisa?

Comment: Já tentou declarar a expressão regular RegExp? var re1 = new RegExp("abc");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) do [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
/\w+\.com(\/[\/\w]*)?$/.test(url);
```

Lembrando de escapar a "/".

```js
var url = "www.url.com/foo/bar/send/123"; 
var res = /\w+\.com(\/[\/\w]*)?$/.test(url);

console.log(url, ' -> ', res);

var url = "www.url.co/foo/bar/send/123"; 
var res = /\w+\.com(\/[\/\w]*)?$/.test(url);

console.log(url, ' -> ', res);
```

Comment: Acredito que funcionou, obrigado! Estava preso na questão de utilizar "\/" para sinalizar barras.

Comment: @Jhonathan com essa resposta se eu tiver a seguinte URL: `qu@alq3ercoisaAqu!->.url.com/foo/bar/send/123` o resultado ainda será `TRUE`

Comment: Esse código te limita a apenas um domínio especifico e não a qualquer domínio.

Comment: @ThiagoOliveira verdade, bem observado.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar esse regex: `/(http:\/\/)?www\.\w+\.com.+/g` da seguinte maneira:

```
var regExp = /(http:\/\/)?www\.\w+\.com.+/g;
var url = 'url-aqui';
var resultado = regExp.test(url); //retorna true ou false
```

Assim você pega na URL o `http://` que pode ou não existir, o `www`, qualquer texto que estiver depois e finalize o domínio com `.com`.

Comment: E se for https, ou ftp ou file?

Comment: Aí você pode modificar a expressão da seguinte maneira: `/(http:\/\/)?(https:\/\/)?(ftp:\/\/)?(file:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.com.+/g`. Assim você pode incluir qualquer protocolo que quiser verificar, e também considerar URLs que não contenham o `www.`

Comment: Com essa resposta se você tiver qualquer-coisa antes do http, também dará `TRUE`, teria que adicionar o `^` depois da `/` de inicio do pattern para ficar direitinho.

Comment: Pode ficar com a expressão desse jeito: `/^((http|https|ftp|file):\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.com.+$/g`.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor para trabalhar com url é por ele em uma string e usa o RegExp, pois ele automaticamente realiza escape das barras, assim você pode escrever sua url de teste normalmente.

```js
var url = "www.url.com/foo/bar/";
r = new RegExp(url);
console.log(r);
```

Pelo que entendi o que você quer verificar é se o domínio esta correto para isso você pode fazer assim.

```js
var dominio = 'www.url.com';
var r = new RegExp(dominio);

console.log(r)

var testes = [
  'www.url.com/foo/bar/send/123',
  'www.url.com/foo/doe/get/123',
  'www.url.co/foo/doe/get/123',
  'http://www.url.com/foo/get/123',
  'http://www.url.co/foo/doe/123',
]

for(var i in testes){
  var url = testes[i];
  console.log(url, url.match(r)!=null);
}
```

E assim para verificar a url com `foo` basta alterar ara `var dominio = 'www.url.com/foo'`

Comment: Cuidado com o ponto no regex, essa regex pode casar com wwwwurl.com sem problemas.